# DB2 - use field as a labeled duration for time calculation

Tags: db2, db2-400

Given a table that looks like this:

```
id  task                     scheduled_date    reminder
--  -----------------------  ----------------  --------
 1  mail january newsletter  2022-01-01        15 days
```

I had planned on executing a query to mimic date addition as in

```
SELECT TASK, SCHEDULED_DATE + 15 DAYS FROM ...

==> 2022-01-16
```

Unfortunately, using the `REMINDER` field gives an error:

```
SELECT TASK, (SCHEDULED_DATE + REMINDER) FROM ...

==>[Code: -182, SQL State: 42816]  [SQL0182] A date, time, or timestamp expression not valid.
```

Is there any way to accomplish using the reminder field as a labeled duration?  (I'm using IBMi DB2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert the string `"15 days"` into an actual duration.

A date durration is a `decimal(8,0)` number representing YYYYMMDD

So 15 days would be `00000015`
1 year, `00010000`
1 year 1 month, one day '00010101`

```
create table testdur (
  datedur decimal(8,0)
);

insert into testdur
  values (15), (10000), (10101), (90), (300);

select current_date as curDate
  , dateDur
  ,current_date + dateDur
from testdur;
```

Results
[image]

Comment: That gave me the needed push in the right direction.  I'll need to store the duration as decimal(8,0) instead of plain text as I originally had it.  Interesting to note that if a query uses a duration in this manner that it must be cast as decimal; you can't just `select curdate + '00000015'`; it must be `select curdate + cast('00000015' as decimal(8,0))`

Answer (score 1):

There is an attempt to implement the [interval](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-interval) function available in Db2 for LUW. It supports **string expression** as a parameter, not just **string constant** as the built-in one.
The result of this function can participate in whatever allowed date arithmetic.
This works on Db2 for LUW v11.1+ and Db2 for IBM i v7.5+ at least.

```
create or replace function interval_d (p_interval varchar (100))
returns dec (8)
contains sql
deterministic 
no external action
begin atomic
  declare v_sign dec (1) default 0;
  declare v_pattern varchar (100) default '([+-]? *[0-9]+) *(\w+)';
  declare v_y int default 0;
  declare v_m int default 0;
  declare v_d int default 0;
  declare v_occ int default 1;
  declare v_num int;
  declare v_kind varchar (10);

  l1: while 1=1 DO
    set v_kind = 
    lower
    (
      regexp_substr 
      (
          p_interval
        , v_pattern
        , 1, v_occ, '', 2
      )
    );
    if v_kind is null then leave l1; end if;
    set v_num =
    int 
    (
      replace
      (
        regexp_substr
        (
            p_interval
          , v_pattern
          , 1, v_occ, '', 1
        )
      , ' ', ''
      )
    );
    if sign (v_num) * v_sign < 0 then 
      signal sqlstate '75001' set message_text = 'Sign of all operands must be the same';
    end if;
    if v_sign = 0 then set v_sign = sign (v_num); end if;
    if v_kind in ('d', 'day', 'days')
      then set v_d = v_d + v_num;
    elseif v_kind in ('mon', 'mons', 'month', 'months')
      then set v_m = v_m + v_num;
    elseif v_kind in ('y', 'year', 'years')
      then set v_y = v_y + v_num;
    else
      signal sqlstate '75000' set message_text = 'wrong duration';
    end if;
    set v_occ = v_occ + 1;
  end while l1;
  if abs (v_d) > 99 then
    set v_m = v_m + v_d / 30, v_d = mod (v_d, 30);
  end if;
  if abs (v_m) > 99 then
    set v_y = v_y + v_m / 12, v_m = mod (v_m, 12);
  end if;
  return v_y * 10000 + v_m * 100 + v_d;
end
```

```
select interval_d (i) as d
from
(
  values
    ('4 years 2 months 3 days')
  , ('3 day 4 year 2 month')
  , ('-4y -2mon -3d') 
) t (i)
```

| D |
| --- |
| 40203 |
| 40203 |
| -40203 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dLiXeXpg)

Comment: Regrettably, I have been unable to create the function.  It seems to squawk at the while/do loop.  However, your answer is quite helpful in demonstrating translation from textual duration to a useable date.  I truly appreciate the effort in creating this example.

Comment: Try to change `while true` to `while 1=1`. Older versions may not support `true`.

Comment: That enabled me to create the function; but when I test it as above it yields `[Code: -420, SQL State: 22018]  [SQL0420] Value for cast argument not valid.`  When I try it with an existing table, I get `[Code: -204, SQL State: 42704]  [SQL0204] ADD_INTERVAL in *LIBL type *N not found.`  I think it's the same problem in both instances as the second error can actually be a mismatch in casting rather than not being found.  But I really don't see how a date is not a date.  :(

Comment: It works on my Db2 v7.5. Unfortunately I don't have an access to any older version to check...

Comment: I think I'm on 7.2.  I've not been able to implement any function that returns a scalar, although I have successfully implemented functions that return a table.  Another fight for another day...  I ended up just adding another date field and using PHP to calculate the date on every insert and update. It simplifies the SQL and is dependable... as long as the PHP app is the only thing that updates the table... smh. Thanks again for your help

Comment: I've slightly rewritten the function to implement the same one available in Db2 for LUW. Just in case...